# Using Model Attributes inside another Model's Factory - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, factory-bot, faker

I have a factory called `Message`, which HABTM `Users`. I want to mock `sender_id` inside the `Message` Factory.
If I do:

```
sender_id  { FactoryGirl.build(:user}.id }
```

I get:

```
FactoryGirl:DuplicateDefinitionError
```

How can I refer to another factory's data attribute (`id` in my case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if it works, what you do is `build` a user (which means no saving to database) and try to get an `id` of unsaved record, which must be a wrong way.

What you can do, is literally create the object `sender` and associate it with the user using `association` method. Accordingly to guides at FactoryGirl you can write:

```
factory :message do
  association :sender, factory: :user
end
```

FactoryGirl has a very wide set of options for associations. This way allows you to create `belongs_to` association, but it is also possible to create `has_many` using callbacks `after_create`.

Please take a look at [associations part in Getting Started](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations). It is a very rich source of knowledge regarding factories.